# Is it possible to get CouchDB to exclude the 'internal' fields _id and _rev when emitting data?

Tags: couchdb

Basically what it says in the title.

Any program making use of my database has no need of the current revision information and how I have labelled the document internally, and including them can hinder iteration over meaningful properties. So why is it included when you make a GET request for a specific document?

Is it possible to get CouchDB to exclude this information?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just query the DB through a [show function](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#show-functions) that filters any undesired fields.

Something like:

```
function(doc, req) {
  delete doc._id;
  delete doc._rev;
  provides('json', function() {
    return {'json': doc};
  });
}
```

Comment: _"The result of a show function is not stored. This means that the function is executed every time a request is made. As a consequence, using map functions might be more efficient. For web and mobile applications, consider whether any computations done in a show function would be better placed in the application tier."_

https://docs.cloudant.com/design_documents.html#show-functions